# Invalid Pointer Operation with Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, delphi, sorting, dynamic, pascal

Heloo guys... Once I try to run this code I am gettin an 'invalid pointer operation' error, what is the problem ? It is supposed to sort those names in that textfile into an alphabetical order (school project).

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;
var
  names : TextFile;
  count : integer=0;
  array : array of string;
  i : integer;

Procedure Load;
 begin
  Reset(names);
  SetLength(array, count - 1);
  for i := 1 to count do ReadLn(names, array[i]);
 end;

begin
  AssignFile(names, 'names.txt');
  Reset(names);
    While not EoF(names) do
      begin
      ReadLn(names);
      Inc(count);
      end;
   Load;
   for i := 1 to count do WriteLn(array[i]);
   ReadLn;
   CloseFile(names);
   Erase(names);
end.
```

Comment: I know its not set yet to sort those items in to an alphabetical order, cause i am not done yet...just have to solve this 'error problem' first.

Comment: If there are some 'syntax mistakes' its because I was writing it from my memory and not copy and pasting it (i also changed names of the variables , cause I had them named in my language(slovak))...I just wrote here something ,very similar, for you to get an idea about my problem

Comment: Why is your array count 0? You're essentially calling `SetLength(Array, 0);`

Comment: it is not...you didnt read carefully

Comment: Got it, you're incrementing it. Still not the right way to do so. Eliminate this Count variable and read `Length(array)` instead.

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't use the extremely old-fashioned file method, and instead use a `TStringList` which has `Count` built-in.

Comment: Thnak you...will try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are zero-based. You need to set the length to `count` and iterate from `0` to `count-1`.

```
SetLength(arr, count);
for i := 0 to count-1 do
  ReadLn(names, arr[i]);
```

Obviously all indexing needs to be changed to be 0-based.

I changed the name of the array to `arr` because `array` is a keyword.

Do not attempt to continue with 1-based indexing. Doing so will cause you endless headaches.

Also you should enable the *range checking* compiler option. Doing so will yield informative errors at runtime if you access an array out of bounds.

Comment: Additionally, If 'names' is empty, code is trying to set the length of 'array' to -1.

Comment: I mean that i tried it but it didnt work and the same error massage appeard again

Comment: would you be okay if I posted here an original file ?

Comment: Good **range checking compiler option** advices and strong patience !